# File Reading average

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I created this code to average test scores, however I put each students test1, test2, test3, etc in an array. Now how can I get the overall average of the test score for one test (ex. q1 is in array index 0, but they are 8 different q1's. How do I get their average?)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Project3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {



        ReadFile r = new ReadFile();
        r.openFile();
        r.readFile();
        r.closeFile();
```

--

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Grades {

    private  Formatter x;
    //Formatter variable- output string to file


    public void openFile(){
        //method to open file
        try{
            x = new Formatter("grades.txt");


        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not find file.");
        }
    }

        public void addRecords(){
        x.format("%d",8);
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", " Thui", "Bhu", 100, 90, 80, 100, 89, 99, 88);
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\n ArianaB", "Smith", 90, 90, 100, 100, 99, 100, 95);
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\n Emily", "Gonzales", 100, 90, 100, 70, 78, 78, 80);
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\n Jenifer", "L", 80, 90, 90, 100, 89, 99, 85);
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\n Maria", "Jones", 65, 72, 77, 68, 62, 70, 65);
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\n Bill", "Gates", 60, 54, 38, 62, 65, 60, 50);
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\n Escobar", "Morris", 83, 77, 88, 76, 79, 72, 76  );
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\n Anne", "Latner", 80, 90, 85, 95, 90, 95, 90  );


        }
        public void closeFile(){
            x.close();
        }
        //



}
```

--

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

import java.util.*;
public class ReadFile {

private Scanner x;

        public void openFile(){
    try{
        x = new Scanner (new File ("grades.txt"));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }}



public void createFile()throws IOException {


    try{
        File file = new File("grades.txt");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);




    while(s.hasNext()){

        {   

        double q1average = 0.0, q2average = 0.0, q3average = 0.0, q4average = 0.0;
        double proji = 0.0, projii =0.0, projiii = 0.0;
        double q1sum = 0.0, q2sum = 0.0, q3sum = 0.0, q4sum = 0.0;
        double proji_sum = 0.0, projii_sum = 0.0, projiii_sum =0.0;
        while(s.hasNext()) {
            String[] split = s.nextLine().split(", ");

            q1sum += Double.parseDouble(split[1]); // add all first grades
            q1average++;

            q2sum += Double.parseDouble(split[2]); // add all first grades
            q2average++;

            q3sum += Double.parseDouble(split[3]); // add all first grades
            q3average++;

            q4sum += Double.parseDouble(split[4]); // add all first grades
            q4average++;

            proji_sum += Double.parseDouble(split[5]); // add all first grades
            proji++;

            projii_sum += Double.parseDouble(split[6]); // add all first grades
            projii++;

            projiii_sum += Double.parseDouble(split[7]); // add all first grades
            projiii++;
            int maxq1 =0;
            if(Double.parseDouble(split[1]) > maxq1) 
                maxq1 = (int) Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
            System.out.println(maxq1);
        }

        double q1_average =  (q1sum/q1average);
        double q2_average = (q2sum / q2average);
        double q3_average = (q3sum / q3average);
        double q4_average = (q4sum / q4average);
        double p1_average = (proji_sum/proji);
        double p2_average = (projii_sum/projii);
        double p3_average = (projiii_sum/projiii);
    }



    }}catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
public void closeFile(){
    x.close();
}
}
```

Comment: And where in the code is the said array?

Comment: You are not put EACH student in array, you put all data in array splitted by , (dot).

Comment: Seems to be homework-time!

Answer (score 2):

The same way you would get the average on paper: add all the individual test scores and divide by their total number. So create a temporary variable and then, in a loop, add up the individual test scores, dividing by the total number of students after the loop.

Comment: how can i do this with only using q1, q2, etc variables?

Comment: Exactly as I said: define an additional variable for each sum or average that you want to have. So you might have a double avgQ1 = 0; and then you have: avgQ1 += q1; inside the loop. After the loop, do avgQ1 /= numStudents. You'll have to define and count the number of students that you've read in for this as well then.

Comment: Though in your case, you'll have to have another loop or some other way of reading in and counting the number of students, before doing the calculation part in the second (your current) loop.

Comment: Does this make sense to you?

Comment: @MartinDinov how do you suppose to make a loop if all data is in one array and each q1 is placed in +8 position? This will be arithmetic stuff and not elegant. So all q's from 1st student position will be +8 indexed in others students. So, it is possible to make a loop for each q's and add +8 iterating over []split array from q's beginnings. But this is not an elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

This will be not very nice way to make it, but it should work. So, your array is `split[]` and it stores all data splitted by `,` (comma). So if you notice,if you add `+8 index` to your first Student `q`'s (`q1` for example is stored in `split[1]`, so +8, and second `Student` `q1` will be stored in `split[9]`) you will get your second Student q's. So can do something like this:

```
int std=0
int q1=0,a=1;
while(a<split.length){
q1+=Integer.parseInt(split[a]);
a+=8;
std++;
}
int result = q1/std;

// This will count all students q1 and take average
```

The same you can make with others q's. But as I said, this is boilerplate code.

Comment: the same range of numbers occurred, and they give 8 different values

Comment: I have already tested it with my string array and it works. add ' , ' in the end of your each line in your file. Because now it seems that each value which is in the end of the line, is embed in the same place where your students name are.

Comment: Just add commas to your end of lines in your file and it should work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have is a multidimensional array. You have multiple test scores ("rows") on multiple lines ("columns"). You need to put each line somewhere so you can recall them later.

You can either do something simple like this:

```
double grades = 0.0;
double sum = 0.0;
while(s.hasNext()) {
    String[] split = s.nextLine().split(", ");

    sum += Double.parseDouble(split[1]); // add all first grades
    grades++;
}
System.out.println(sum / grades);
```

Or something more complex:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> allGrades = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
while(s.hasNext()) {
    allGrades.add(Arrays.asList(s.nextLine().split(", ")));
}

StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
int cols = allGrades.get(0).size();
for(int c = 1; ;) { // outer for every test

    double sum = 0.0;
    double count = 0.0;
    double max = 0.0;
    for(int r = 0; r < allGrades.size(); r++) { // inner for every person
        count++;
        double grade = Double.parseDouble(allGrades.get(r).get(c));
        sum += grade;
        if(grade > max) {
            max = grade;
        }
    }

    results.append("[test ");
    results.append(c);
    results.append(": avg = ");
    results.append(sum / count);
    results.append(", max = ");
    results.append(max);
    results.append(']');

    if(++c < cols) { // fence post logic...
        results.append(", ");
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println(results);
```

Or maybe like this:

```
double[] avgs = new double[7];
double count = 0.0;
while(s.hasNext()) {
    String[] split = s.nextLine().split(", ");

    for(int i = 0, k = 1; k < split.length; i++, k++) {
        avgs[i] += Double.parseDouble(split[k]);
    }

    count++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < avgs.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("test avg " + (i + 1) + ": " + (avgs[i] / count));
}
```

Comment: for the simpler one... do I have to do a new while loop for each test?

Comment: Not necessarily, you could store the results in an array. See another snippet I've added. But in general because of the 2D aspect you are going to have a nested loop. Either that or hard code it somehow like you are suggesting.

Comment: how would suggest to go about to find the max of each test

Comment: Make a variable for it and in the loop you'll say something like `if(score > max) max = score;`.

Comment: i did that in the while loop but it only printed the first number of each variable

Comment: I added it to one of my examples. Loops like this are the kind of thing you will just have to tinker with until you get it. If possible these things are also a lot simpler if you don't try to do it all in one procedure. Instead, like I suggested, put the data somewhere that's easier to recall it. For example, make a simple class purely so you can separate the names from the scores. `class TestScores { String firstName; String lastName; double[] testScores; }`